# Google Formsで編集画面が開けない

Tags: google-spreadsheet

Google spreadsheetでアンケートのFormsを連携させているのですが、編集画面として開くことができません。以前まではそうではなかった覚えがあるのですが、最近編集が必要になったので開いてみようとしたら**閲覧モード**でしか開きません。何が原因でしょうか？

ちなみに、Formと連動しているspreadsheetの共有情報では、私のアカウントはownerとなっています。ownerであれば、Formの編集権限はあるとの認識です。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

編集画面を開こうとした手順です。
下記のようにクリックして、Formの編集画面開きます。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

FormをEdit modeで開くと、下記の画面が開きます。
しかし、下記の画面は編集画面ではなく、閲覧しかできない**閲覧モード**画面です。
ですので、編集モードでは画面は開くことができなかったということになります。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

上記のURLを確認すると、末尾が`/viewform?edit_requested=true`となっていました。
この末尾を手動で`/edit`と変えて再更新をかけても、自動的に末尾が変えられ`/viewform?edit_requested=true`となります。

やはり、ownerであるにも関わらず、編集権限がないと見なされて自動で閲覧モードに飛ばされている気がします。何か別に制限されているということがあるでしょうか？

また、複数のグーグルアカウントでログインしていたので違うアカウントの権限が誤って参照されているかと考え、全てのアカウントから一度ログアウトして、対象の１つのアカウントでログインしてから、編集画面を開きましたが、同様の結果でした。

また、シークレットウィンドウで開き、対象のグーグルアカウントだけでログインし、同様の方法で編集画面を開きましたが、同様の結果でした。

Comment: 編集画面を開けないという内容ですがスプレットシート からは開けるのでしたら、どの画面から何をした時に開けないのか、を明記した方がいいと思います。ちなみに少し手元で確認しましたが、Google Formsのホーム画面から作成したFormsをクリックしたら編集できる画面（URLの末尾は、`/edit`）は開きました。

Comment: 編集画面はどの方法でも開けません。質問本文に内容を編集、追記しましたのでご確認ください。`/edit`の末尾を手動で入力しましたがこれもうまくいきませんでした。

Comment: なるほど。編集画面は出ていないのですか。失礼しました。再現できていないのですが、私の手元での確認結果だけ共有します。①オーナーアカウントでは`/edit`にリダイレクト／②その状態で別のgoogleアカウントに切り替え（画面の右上にあるアカウントのアイコンで切り替え）で右下に「編集リクエストを送信」のある編集不可の画面／③ボタンを押すと①と同じ画面になる。／④②のアカウントには共有もしていないので閲覧画面が見えていることがおかしい→きちんとアカウント切り替えされていないように見える。／⑤Chromeのシークレットウィンドウ（ブラウザの右上の・が3つ縦に並んだところのメニューから選択で起動）にてフォームのURLにアクセスするとログインが求められるので②のアカウントでログイン→アクセス権が必要ですの表示。／⑥再度新しいシークレットウィンドウを開き①のアカウントでログインしたら①と同じ編集画面。／画面としては②で同じ状態になりましたが他のアカウントの影響があるように感じました。ログアウトされたと書かれているので可能性としては低いですが、念のためシークレットウィンドウで試してみると切り分けができるかもしれません。（すみません、私はこれ以上お力になれそうにありません。どなたか識者がいれば良いのですが、「Google ドライブのサポートに連絡する」もご検討ください。）

Comment: 検証いただきありがとうございます。シークレットウィンドウで試してみましたが、同様の結果でした。「Google ドライブのサポートに連絡する」をしてみようと思います。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

「Google ドライブのサポートに連絡する」を行いその回答に基づき再度調査した結果、フォームの権限設定に該当アカウントの編集権限がなかったため、編集できなかったことが原因であったことが分かった。

上記の原因は単純なことだが、なぜ気づかなかったかというと、それに紐づくフォームの権限設定は、スプレッドシートの権限設定と連動していると勘違いしていたためである。

もう少し詳しく経緯を書くと、G-suiteを会社組織で使用しているのだが、アカウントadmin（管理者アカウント）、アカウントB（以前の担当者）、アカウントC（私）があり、

１．アカウントBで、スプレッドシート(Sとする)とそれに紐づくフォーム(Fとする)でアンケート機能を作成。SとFのオーナーはアカウントB。
２．アカウントBが退社。SとFのオーナーがアカウントadminに移譲される。
３. Sの改修が必要だったので、アカウントadminは、アカウントCをSのオーナーにした。
４．Fの改修が必要になった。アカウントCはSのオーナーなので、Fも編集できると思ってFを開くが編集モードにならない。
５．今回の調査が始まった。